# How to fire an UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a position programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to send an UILongPressGestureRecognizer without user interaction on an specific position of an UIWebView. The proyect I'm working on is intended to be uploaded to the AppStore, so the given solution must be "legal".

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without user interaction."  Do you mean you want to trigger the action that the gestureRecognizer would take had the user long pressed at that point?  If so, then you can just call it's target method...

Comment: No, I dont want to call it's target. On a webview when the user holds on a word this word gets selected, this is the effect that I want to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Have the click on the webpage send a URL to the application when the conditions are met on the webpage.  Do a google search on URL schemes (there's quite a few examples) and set up a handler in your app.  Use your webpage html/javascript code to detect the long press, and when it happens send the URL scheme.   For example, just like you send a "mailto:" url to send an signal to your email app, you use a "myFoobarapp:" url to trigger signals to your app. The application detects the URL scheme and does what you want.  Using URL schemes is the approved method of communicating from a web page to your app.  Make sure you look at the existing url schemes so the one you pick (i.e., myFoobarapp) isn't already taken.